# how to create control dynamically in jface wizrd

Tags: jface

I am developing eclipse plugin and I want to create jface Text boxes in loop dynamically. 
is there a way of doing it in eclipse plugin developement? 
do I need to redraw or something after I add Text boxes dynamically

Answer (score 1):

You might need to call Composite.layout() on the  parent composite of the freshly created control, depending on how you write the code.

Answer (score 0):

you may create all your controls but use a conditional statement to hide/show and update information in the controls